# Frameworks & Doneworks: Do you thinks it is cool to use those?

Tags: frameworks

By using somebody else's works you advertize the authors of those works (At least, among other programmers). Do you think it is cool?

Comment: Hi Hoperty, is there any chance you could expand on the question a little?

Comment: A donework is work that is done by somebody else but not you and you use it because you do not want to do your job.

Answer (score 1):

This line of questioning could go up one more level and become "Programming Languages: Do you think it's cool to use those?" Because someone(s) wrote those too. I can continue this up to the types of computers, to the components, etc...

Monet did not make the brushes or the paint or the canvas (well maybe, not sure). But who creates those building blocks is not quite what stands out at the end.

Languages/Frameworks/etc were built and released to be utilized by the masses (or make money for the creators).

Comment: I'm not sure where you going with this. If "doneworks" is not up to your standards (or you just do not want to use something someone else built) and your up to the challenge you should build your own. This is one driver of progress. Just because something is out there does not seem like a good reason to linger behind in anything. And if you find yourself doing that, that is a question of person and not of what "doneworks" are out there.

Comment: Those are not programers who use frameworks; those are lego builders! =)

Comment: And who doesn't love playing with legos?

Comment: And who doesn't love playing with legos? - Every adult!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's always cool. Be more efficient, reduce redundancy, promote other useful code.

If you're trying to learn though, reading and understanding the framework you're using is very helpful. There are always other things you can be programming and learning, not necessarily reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If using their work has saved you time reimplementing the same thing (but with more bugs) then don't they deserve credit?

Or put another way, stealing other peoples' work without credit (or paying them, depending on whether we're talking about free or commercial software here) isn't cool.

Of course, nobody's stopping you from writing your own framework, if that's what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of programming you're doing.

Are you doing it to achieve a finished program?  Then a framework could save you a lot of time.

Are you doing it to create something truly original?  Then a framework might simply tie you into an existing way of thinking.

Rembrandt made his own paints.  Michelangelo selected his own marble from the quarry.  Alan Kay said "People who are really serious about software should make their own hardware".  The Excel team famously has their own compiler.  The iPhone ain't just an alternate firmware for the Blackberry.  ISTM if you want to be at the very top of your game, you've got to get down and dirty with the nitty gritty of it.

I don't know anything about advertising, other programmers, or what's "cool", so I can't respond to those parts of your question.

Comment: If your a hardware maker, make hardware, but if you are a software maker do make software. Why program at all, indeed! All is done!